I don't want my email form to redirect to my php file
I created an email form on my website to collect emails using javascript and php. Initially, I attempted to prevent it from redirecting me to www.mywebsite.com/send_email.php by using fetch, but it still redirected me to another page that displayed the message 'Message Sent! Thank you!'. Eventually, I managed to resolve the issue by embedding the script within the html file. However, I'm curious to know if there is a way to achieve the same outcome of loading on the same home page while keeping the javascript code in a separate js file linked to the html file.
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
const messageDiv = document.getElementsByName('message');
const errorMessageDiv = document.getElementById('error-message');
      
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
      
        const formData = new FormData(form);
      
        fetch('send_email.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
        })
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.text(); 
          } else {
            throw new Error('Error sending email.'); 
          }
        })
        .then(message => {
          messageDiv.textContent = message;
          messageDiv.style.display = 'block'; 
          form.reset(); 
        })
        .catch(error => {
          errorMessageDiv.textContent = 'Message Sent! Thank you!';
          errorMessageDiv.style.display = 'block'; 
        });
      });

send_email.php
<?php
$to = 'info@website.com';
$from = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['username'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$headers = "From: $from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from \r\n";

$body = "Name: $name\n";
$body .= "Email: $from\n";
$body .= "Subjectt: $subject\n";
$body .= "Message:\n$message";

if (mail($to, 'New Message from Your Website', $body, $headers)) {
  echo "Message sent successfully!"; // Success message
} else {
  echo "An error occurred while sending the email."; // Error message
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>

I tried to use fetch with the index.html but it still gives me the same result.

You could solve this with JS, however it is not required. A common pattern is to send the user to your PHP script in a POST, it does work (send email in your case), and then redirect back to another page. That page can be the original page or a “thank you” page, or you can conditionally redirect depending on if there’s an error, and you can use the quest string or session to pass a success or failure message. Or, AJAX/fetch with JSON for status.

That said, don’t be surprised if your emails don’t all get through. In modern times, the FROM portion of an email is really hard to be dynamic because of MTA rules for DNS including SPF and DKIM.

You printing $response variable at the end of your code. But i could not see where you have assigned it. It might be an error 500. check you console for error.

You should also rather not have a \r\n after your last header.

Using fetch() definitely won't send you to another page. At a guess maybe you had a javascript error which stopped it handling the form submission event and running the fetch(). Try checking the console for js errors

You aren't being redirected.
You try to echo json_encode($response);, but $response doesn't exist!
So PHP throws an error, and your Javascript goes into the catch section, where your message is displayed:
        .catch(error => {
          errorMessageDiv.textContent = 'Message Sent! Thank you!';
          errorMessageDiv.style.display = 'block'; 
        });

Try changing your PHP script to something like this:
if (mail($to, 'New Message from Your Website', $body, $headers)) {
  $status = 200;
  $response = ['status' => 'Message sent successfully!']; // Success message
} else {
  $status = 500;
  $response = ['status' => 'An error occurred while sending the email.']; // Error message
}

http_response_code($status);
echo json_encode($response);


